# How to get an average pipe flow speed

Tags: pipe, monitoring, tail, fifo, pv

If `myfile` is increasing over time, I can get the number of line per second using

```
tail -f | pv -lr > /dev/null
```

It gives instantaneous speed, not average.

How can I get the average speed (i.e the integral of the speed function `v(t)` over the monitoring time).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `pv` 1.2.0 (December 2010) and above, it's with the `-a` option:

Here with both current and average, line-based:

```
$ find / 2> /dev/null | pv -ral > /dev/null
[6.28k/s] [70.1k/s]
```

With 1.3.8 (October 2012) and newer, you can also use `-F`/`--format` with `%a`:

```
$ find / 2> /dev/null | pv -lF 'current: %r, average: %a'  > /dev/null
current: [4.66k/s], average: [ 218k/s]
```

Note that `tail -f` starts by dumping the last 10 lines of the file. Use `tail -n 0 -f file | pv -la` to avoid that bias in your average speed calculation.